# Nested if function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, nested

So I want a code that will execute the following...

If K= Business and E= null 
highlight E

and

If K= Business and F= null 
Highlight F

Every time i try it says type mismatch or object error

```
Sub business() 
    Dim a As String 
    Dim b As String 
    Dim c As String

    Set a.Value = Range("K2:K300") 
    Set b.Value = Range("E2:E300") 
    Set c.Value = Range("F2:F200")

    If a = "Email" And b = "" Or c = "" Then 
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 
    End If 
End Sub
```

[This is the snippet of my worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL8VH.png)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52268098/edit) your question with the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: This doesn't require VBA - you can do this with conditional formatting.

Comment: So I want a code that i have got so far

Sub bussiness()
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Set a.Value = Range("K2:K300")
Set b.Value = Range("E2:E300")
Set c.Value = Range("F2:F200")
If a = "Email" And b = "" Or c = "" Then
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
End Sub

Comment: You are setting `a`, `b`, and `c` to arrays, then testing them in the `If` statement as if they were individual values. Just put a conditional format in column E and one in column F - something like `=AND(K2="Email",E2="")` and `=AND(K2="Email",F2="")`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am adding this code as a part of a big macro that is why i am looking for a vba code and not conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid loops:

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(11) ' reference your database (assuming header row is row 1, starts at column 1 and no header is blank)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "Business") > 0 Then 'if any "business" occurrence
        .Replace what:="Business", replacement:=1, lookat:=xlWhole ' mark "business" row with a number
        On Error Resume Next
        With Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow, .Offset(, -6)) ' reference "marked" rows cell in column E (6th column left of column K)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbRed 'mark any referenced range blank cell in red
            .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbRed 'mark any referenced range 1 column right blank cell in red
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Replace what:=1, replacement:="Business", lookat:=xlWhole ' get "business" back in place
    End If
End With
```